# Looping Email Workflow with Condition

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow, designer-workflow, loop

i need to create a email loop workflow with condition but i confused to create on sharepoint designer, example flowchart below

[image]

is there who know to create it?

Comment: Here's a good [example workflow](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/q/234080/65896).

Answer (score 2):

**Try to do the following:**

- Create a new variable called `Today` then set it to **Current Date**.
- Add a new `Stage`, rename it as you prefer.
- Add `Loop with condition` while the `Returned` field become `yes`
- Insert `Add Time to Date` action to add **3** days to the `Today` variable (output to date variable).
- Then add `Pause` action to pause until **3** days (date variable) then check the returned field value again!

  - If `No` loop again.
  - Otherwise, exit loop and End Workflow!

[image]

Comment: Hi M.Qassas, thanks for your help. i've tried to create the workflow, but the email sent every second. the pause until variable date is not work. i still try to fix that :D . do you have any suggestion?

Comment: try to log the variable date to check its value? it should pause until today + 3days! also, share what you have did?